# Inflection points in a function with unkown constants

Tags: calculus

Can anyone solve the following problem?

For what constants $b$ and $c$ does the curve $y=cx^3+\exp(bx)$ have:

i) 0 inflection points

ii) 1 inflection point

iii) 2 inflection points

iv) more than 2 inflection points

I'm lost past knowing I have to take the second derivative and setting it to $0$, which means solving for $x$ in
$$0 = 6cx+b^2\exp(bx).$$

**Case 1**: 1 inflection point. $-6cx$ intersects $b^2 e^{bx}$ at a tangent then

$$-6cx = b^3e^{ba}(x-a)+b^2e^{ba}$$
therefore$$b^3e^{ba}=-6c$$
$$a=\frac{1}{b}\ln(\frac{-6c}{b^3})$$
and
$$b^2e^{ba}-ab^3e^{ba}=0$$$$b^2e^{ba}(1-ab)=0$$
substituting
$$\frac{-6c}{b}(1-\ln(\frac{-6c}{b^3}))=0$$

If c or b = 0 then the equation has no solution therefore the equation is satisfied for only
$$c=-\frac{eb^3}{6}$$

Comment: What do you get for the second derivative?

Comment: And how do you know you have to take the second derivative? Are you aware of some relation between second derivatives and inflection points?

Comment: The values of x such that y''(x) = 0 are the x coordinates of inflection points.

Comment: The second derivative is $y''= 6cx + b^2\exp(bx)$

Comment: Good! So, now what do you do?

Comment: By the way, if you want to be sure I will see a comment intended for me, you have to include @Gerry in it.

Comment: @Gerry . I set y'' = 0, then attempted to solve for x. I tried taking logarithms to get rid of the exponential. I then attempted to express logarithms as an integral of 1/t. Didn't really work out in any meaningful way, so now I'm stuck.

Comment: Well, you can't solve for $x$, but you don't have to – all you're asked to do is arrange the number of solutions, not find them. So, think about what the graph of $y=6cx+b^2e^{bx}$ looks like for various values of the parameters $b$ and $c$, and how often it crosses the $x$-axis. Possibly easier, think about the graph of $y=6cx$, and the graph of $y=-b^2e^{bx}$, and where the two graphs intersect.

Comment: @Gerry . That really doesn't help me. Even if I could picture both graphs and their intersection points in my head (which I personally find difficult, and I'd have to solve this question without the aid of any form of electronics), that doesn't give me any numerical answers, and even if they did, I still need a rigorous proof to back my solutions. I know I don't actually have to solve for x, that's just the only way I could think of to get a solution. Picturing the answer, however, also doesn't give me a solution.

Comment: The graph of $y=6cx$ is a straight line through the origin. The graph of $y=-b^2e^{bx}$ is an exponential curve, same shape as $y=e^x$ (if $b>0$) or $y=e^{-x}$ (if $b<0$), only entirely below the $x$-axis instead of above it (because of the $-b^2$). So, how many times can a straight line hit an exponential curve? It can miss entirely, or hit it just once, or exactly twice – I'm confident you can see that. One way to hit it once is to be tangent to it. You can use Calculus to figure out conditions on $b$ and $c$ for that to happen. If you move away from those conditions (continued)

Comment: (continued) in one direction, you get no intersections; in the other direction, two. You can also hit once without it being tangent; the changeover between this way of hitting once, and hitting twice, I think is when the line is vertical. Anyway, sketch the graph of $y=e^x$ – just a sletch, it doesn't have to be real accurate – and imagine what happens with lines of different slopes through the origin, and you'll see all the possibilities, and the borders between them. And once you see what's going on, then you can set to work giving rigorous arguments.

Comment: So, does that help any?

Comment: @Gerry. Not particularly TBH. I forgot to mention that it's a mock exam question that should be solved in roughly 10 minutes. Considering all sorts of cases isn't practical time wise.

Comment: And how do you expect to answer a question that asks you to distinguish among four cases, without "considering all sorts of cases"? The way to solve a math question in 10 minutes, is to invest a couple of hours in understanding how a similar question is solved, so when you see that question on an exam, you'll know what to do with it. So, don't just pooh-pooh what I've written on the grounds that it looks like more than 10 minutes' work – study it, engage with it, try to understand it, come back with more questions about it, learn something from it. You'll be glad you did.

Comment: Waiting to hear from you.

Comment: A similar question would be find k such that a quadratic with a constant term k has 0,1, or 2 roots. All you're required to do is set up one equation/inequality then solve it in various ways. I didn't have to consider cases starting from the beginning each time. Telling me to look at similar questions for hours before the exam is just called studying. Just thinking practically, finding questions that I could solve so that I'm prepared for questions like these is quite difficult. The difficulty isn't with the question, it's with the function.

Comment: And I find it odd as to why you wastes both of our times by asking me the relationship between inflection points and second derrivatives. We can hopefully both see that the problem is applying the question to the function. So now in order to practice I need to find similar difficulty functions. What defines a similarly difficult function, and not one that's impossible or too easy is lost on me, considering I can't even solve this one.

Comment: I'm not a mathematician @Gerry, I'm studying to be an engineer. I like practicality, and I'm just trying to find the most reasonable answer. And the most reasonable answer right now is that they put the question on the exam to prevent people from getting 100% and it can't be reasonably solved on an exam. If you're convinced it can, don't try to give me vague strategies for solution, find the solution yourself and show me that it can be reasonably solved by someone prepared in 10-20 mins. That's if you actually want to find the solution yourself.

Comment: You want me to solve the problem for you. I want you to solve the problem yourself. I haven't given you "vague strategies for solution", I've told you exactly what to do, if only you will engage seriously with what I Have written. Why don't you try at least a little part of it – use Calculus to find conditions on $b$ and $c$ for the straight line with equation $y=6cx$ to be tangent to the curve with equation $y=-b^2e^{bx}$. I'll meet you more than halfway: at the point $(x,y)$ of tangency, both of the equations must be satisfied, and the derivatives must be equal. Continued...

Comment: .... That gives you three equations relating $x,y,b,c$, which you want to fiddle with to get a single equation relating $b$ and $c$. Why not try it? Can't hurt, and you might learn something useful.

Comment: @GerryMyerson 2 things you should realize. 1: You haven't told me anything I didn't know before. 2: I never said your method didn't give me a solution, I said it was an inefficient means to a solution. To demonstrate my point, I have included the tangency case (which only answers half of the first part of the question). This is only some fraction of the answer and it took up 4 minutes and 32 seconds when written on paper (this time was not spent thinking, only writing). So now you know that the method you propose isn't very useful. Hope you learned something new about impracticality.

Comment: Perhaps so as not to waste your own time and mine, the next time you post a question you could tell us what you already know about the question. The tangency case is a very large fraction of the answer, since $c=-(e/6)b^3$ separates the no-intersection region from the two-intersection region. I would be surprised to learn of a more efficient way to solve the problem. And considering that, aside from one brief comment by @GTony, I'm the only person to show any interest in your question, you might consider whether it's proper to be rude to me.

Comment: Oh dear... Sometimes, conversations on this site really go south. To complete a problem like this one without electronic aid in just  few minutes seems that it would require some fairly well-developed "graph sense", i.e., being able to roughly visualize the relevant functions, in particular, $6cx$ and $b^2\exp(bx)$, for positive and negative values of $b$ and $c$. I haven't got a lot of time right now, but I'll try to come back in a little bit and post the most efficient solution I can find. I think the OP has certainly shown effort in the way we request here at MSE.

Comment: @Gerry Would me stating all I knew really aided you in any way? Despite me saying I knew I had to take the second derrivative, you still made me state the relationship between second derrivatives and inflection points... I might have been rude, but perhaps you can figure out why.

Comment: @GTony, yes, OP has certainly shown considerable effort. This wasn't the case with the original version of the question, and I imagine that was what led to the close votes.

Comment: @GerryMyerson, as the first commenter, I guess I know that. Thanks, though. Now I'm going to write an answer, rather than sit here in the comments dealing in recriminations. The close votes are not of interest to me.

Comment: @GTony, I know you know what the problem used to look like, but it's possible someone else will come here who doesn't. Also, I thought that your pointing out that "OP has certainly shown effort in the way we request here at MSE" was directed at users voting to close, but I guess I jumped to a conclusion there. Anyway, I'm happy to read that you are going to write an answer.

Comment: @Ohmyland, does my answer resolve your question? If you have further questions, please let me know.

Comment: Now that @GTony has posted an answer for you, Ohmyland, may I encourage you to engage with it and, if you find it resolves your question, may I suggest you "accept" that answer by clicking in the check mark next to it?

Comment: @Gerry you clearly have no understanding of this discussion.

Comment: You might be right. Would you like to enlighten me?

Comment: @Gerry not in the slightest. Reread if you want, you might be able to figure it out. Either way, I'm not reading or replying to anything else on this thread. I can use that time for something more productive, like solving the question myself.

Comment: If you find a better solution, I hope you'll come back to share it with us.

Answer (score 2):

The work you've done is good, and this is the kind of question I probably would *not* put on a calculus test. Anything where you have to solve equations involving polynomials and exponentials tends to get messy, and I usually use tests for... other purposes.

Anyway, you got the second derivative: $f''(x)=6cx+b^2\exp(bx)$. This equals zero, as you noted, precisely when $$-6cx = b^2\exp(bx).$$ Now, that exponential term has one of two behaviors: if $b>0$, it is increasing and concave up for all $x$, and if $b<0$ is it decreasing and concave up for all $x$. (If $b=0$, or if $c=0$, then there's not much to talk about, and I leave those cases to you.) In either case, there's no way for a straight line to intersect it more than twice, so we will never have more than two inflection points.

We quickly obtain one easy result: If $b$ and $c$ have the same sign, then the second derivative is $0$ exactly once. A line with negative slope intersects an exponential growth curve one time; similarly for a line with positive slope and an exponential decay curve. We could prove this rigorously, but we've only got 10 minutes for this question, right?

If $b$ and $c$ differ in sign, then there is a bit more to talk about. As $c$ increases in absolute value, we should pass from $0$ solutions, to $1$ solution (at tangency) to $2$ solutions. Note that the tangent case does not give us an inflection point, because the second derivative, although it momentarily equals $0$, does not change signs! To find that cutoff value, you can do the work you've already begun, and conclude that:

$$-6cx = b^3e^{ba}(x-a)+b^2e^{ba}$$

for all $x$. Comparing slopes, this gives us: $$b^3e^{ba}=-6c$$ and comparing intercepts, we obtain $$ab^3e^{ba}=b^2e^{ba}.$$

This second equation tells us that $a=\frac1b$ (since $b\ne 0$), which we can plug into the first equation to obtain: $$c=\frac{-eb^3}{6}.$$

Thus, if $b$ and $c$ have the same sign, then we have one inflection point. If $0\le\frac{-c}{b^3}\le\frac{e}{6}$, we have no inflection point, and if $\frac{-c}{b^3}>\frac{e}6$, then we have two inflection points.

More succinctly the number of inflection points (including the $0$ cases) is:

$$\begin{cases}0 & -cb^{-3}\in \left[0,\frac{e}6\right]\text{, or if }b=c=0 \\ 1 & -cb^{-3}\in\left(-\infty,0\right)\text{, or if }b=0,c\ne 0 \\ 2 & -cb^{-3}\in\left(\frac{e}6,\infty\right)\end{cases}$$